# How to add an image URL to firebase database when the database dictionary is in another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a view controller (UserProfilePage.swift) where I need to add a profile picture and add the URL to the database. But the dictionary that adds values to the database is in another view controller (SignUpScreen.swift). Here is the code where I add the image in the UserProfilePage.swift:

```
extension UserProfilePage: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        // To choose the edited image
        if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {

            databaseUserProfileImage = selectedImage
            userProfileImage.image = selectedImage

            // Upload image to firebase
            guard let imageData = selectedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4) else {
                return
            }

            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://smallworld-89f21.appspot.com")


        } else if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            userProfileImage.image = selectedImage
        }
        // To dismiss the picker after selecting the image
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Here is the code where I create the dictionary in SignUpScreen.swift:

```
let values = ["Email": email, "Username": username, "Country": country, "UserID": userID, "ProfilePictureURL": ""]
```

As you can see in the code, I have a key for the url of the image. How can I update the dictionary when I upload the image from another view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it an instance variable

```
var values = [String:Any]()
```

then do

```
values["ProfilePictureURL"] =  // someValue
```

BTW `info` gives a `UIImage` instance not a url , then you should convert to data and upload